# Porting / Convert Windows Phone App (Silverlight) to Universal App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, converters, porting, win-universal-app

I am new for this side.
I wonder if it's easy to make the portability of a windows phone 8.1 application for a universal app?

What is the easiest way to do it?

thanks

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to do some porting of code, not all API's available for 8.1 are available in Universal Apps as yet.

The easiest way to achieve maximum code share is to add another project to your solution that targets Universal. When you have done this, I would then add a another project to your solution of type "Portable Class Library (PCL)" that can be shared between the 8.1 app and the universal app (as well as Xbox, Android/iOS with xamarin should future requirements need it). You can then move/refactor/port as much of you 8.1 logic into the PCL as possible. This approach should mean maximum reuse of your business/service/data code.

Comment: Thanks You. Already gave an idea of the situation.

I have to better study this situation and how hard this can be.

best regards

Answer (score 2):

There is a free tool that helps alot with the conversion. Check out this page http://www.mobilize.net/silverlight

if this link fails try googling Mobilize.NET Corporation  and the file installer is named MobilizeNetSilverlightBridge.msi

Comment: this is not a very future proof answer because if the link goes down this answer will be useless an probably be down voted.